# Require.js is hurting my brain. Some fundamental questions about the way it loads scripts/modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, module, requirejs

Let's assume this is my config.js or main.js:

```
require.config({
    // paths are analogous to old-school <script> tags, in order to reference js scripts
    paths: {
        jquery: "libs/jquery-1.7.2.min",
        underscore: "libs/underscore-min",
        backbone: "libs/backbone-min",
        jquerymobile: "libs/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min",
        jquerymobilerouter: "libs/jquery.mobile.router.min"
    },
    // configure dependencies and export value aliases for old-school js scripts
    shim: {
        jquery: ["require"],
        underscore: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        jquerymobilerouter: ["jquery", "backbone", "underscore"],
        jquerymobile: ["jquery", "jquerymobilerouter", "backbone", "underscore"]
    }
});
require(["jquery", "backbone", "underscore", "app/app.min", "jquerymobilerouter", "jquerymobile"], function ($, Backbone, _, App) {
    console.log($);
    console.log(Backbone);
    console.log(_);
    $("body").fadeIn(function () {
        App.init();
    });
});
```

1. If I understand correctly, the `paths` config option allows you to reference scripts, a-la the `<script>` tag within HTML. Assuming this is the case, do I still need to alias scripts like jQuery with a `$` or underscore with a `_` in my actual require statement below? It seems strange that I'd have to, given that if you reference jQuery with a standard `<script>` tag, `$` can be used throughout your script automatically. Shouldn't it be the same using the `paths`?
2. I'm new to the `shim` config option, which I understand has replaced the deprecated `order!` plugin. What does the `exports` property actually DO? It doesn't seem to create an alias for a script; for example, if I set the `exports` for underscore to `"whatever"`, and then try to `console.log(whatever)`, it's undefined. So what's the point?
3. How would scripts like jQuery be properly used "globally?" That is, what's the proper way to be able to use the `$` alias within my App.js module, or any other module in my "app" folder? Do I have to require jQuery within every individual module and alias `$` every single time? Or is the way I've done it here the proper way?

I'd greatly appreciate any other criticisms of this particular script as well; the documentation for Require.js, in my opinion, leaves much to be desired; things I'd really like to know more about seem to get glossed over and leave me scratching my head.

Comment: I wish I could send a screenshot of this question to every new user as an example of how to properly ask a question.

Comment: @MikeRobinson yes that's true. Lately i have no time for answers but for such a good question i'll try to answer it

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Paths tell require.js where to look when you require that dependency.

   For example i have things configured like this:

   ```
   "paths": { 
       "jquery": "require_jquery"
   },
   "shim": {
       "jquery-cookie"  : ["jquery"],
       "bootstrap-tab"  : ["jquery"],
       "bootstrap-modal": ["jquery"],
       "bootstrap-alert": ["jquery"]
   },
   ```

   this means that every time in a module I do

   ```
   define( ['jquery']
   ```

   requirejs loads the file `require_jquery` from the main path instead of trying to load jquery.js. In your case it would load the jQuery source file, which would then be globally available. I personally don't like that approach and for that reason in the require_jquery.js file I do:

   ```
   define( ["jquery_1.7.2"], function() {
       // Raw jQuery does not return anything, so return it explicitly here.
       return jQuery.noConflict( true );
   } );
   ```

   which means that jQuery will be defined only inside my modules. (This is because i write Wordpress plugins and so I can include my own version of jQuery without touching the outside version)
2. Exports (reading from the docs  simply should be the name of the module you are using so that it can be detected if loading went correctly. [Here](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim) is explained. So if you want to set an export for underscore it should be `_`
3. jQuery should be global as I explained, if you simply import it the file is executed and jQuery is global

EDIT - to answer the comments.

1. yes i mean that, you must export $ or jQuery for jQuery and _ for backbone. From what i got from the docs this is needed only in some edge cases and would not be necessary for libraries that declare themselves in the global namespace as jQuery.

   I think that requirejs needs them when it has to fallback from loading jQuery from a CDN. i think that requirejs first tries to load jQuery from the CDN, then makes a check to verify that it was loaded correctly by checking that the "exported" variable exists, and if it doesn't it loads it form the local filesystem (if you had configured fallbacks, of course). This is something that it's needed when requirejs can't see a 404 coming back.
2. jQuery is globally available because it's declared global. If you simply load and execute the jQuery script, you will end up with two globals, `$` and `jQuery` (or you can do as i did and avoid that). Inside the `define()` function you can alias jQuery to be whatever you want.

   ```
   define( [ 'jquery' ], function( jq ) {
       // jq is jquery inside this function. if you declared it 
       // globally it will be also available as $ and jQuery
   } );
   ```

Comment: That clear up paths for me, so thanks. Two more questions, though:

1.) When you say exports "should" be the name of the module, you mean what the actual alias of the lib is? Like "$" for jQuery, for example? Does this mean you can't just assign an arbitrary export value? I had read the Requirejs docs, and they didn't help much at all.

2.) I'm not sure I follow on jQuery's global availability as per your example. Is it globally available BECAUSE I've used a path alias, or simply because of the way it's aliased in the define block?

Comment: @J.KyMarsh i modified my answer.

Comment: @J. Ky Marsh: I'm with you. The RequireJS docs, though very big, don't help me much.

Answer (score 23):

Just to clear up any confusion around `exports`, it's assumed that any shim library attaches a property to the global context (`window` or `root`), or modifies an already-existing global property (e.g. a jQuery plugin).  When requireJS gets the command to load a shimmed dependency, it examines the global context for a property matching the `exports` value of that shim config, and if it finds it, returns it as the value of that module.  If it doesn't find it, then it loads the associated script, waits for it to execute, then finds the global symbol and returns it.

An important fact to remember is that unless the shim config contains an `exports` value, any `init` method on that config will NOT be executed.  The dependency loader must locate a value for the module (which is what `exports` specifies) before that module can be initialized, which is why the property is required if there is a shim `init` for that module.

update: I also need to point out that if the module in question calls `define` anywhere, any shim config you have for that module will be ignored.  This actually caused me some headaches because I wanted to use the shim config to call jQuery's `jQuery.noConflict(true)` method to un-globify jQuery and keep it scoped to just the modules that require it, but couldn't manage to get it working. (See update at bottom for info on how to easily do this using map config instead of shim config.)

update 2: A recent question on the requireJS google group made me realize that my explanation might be slightly misleading, so I'd like to clarify.  RequireJS will only re-use a shimmed dependency *if it was loaded via requireJS at least once*.  That is to say, if you simply have a `<script>` tag on the hosting page (say, for example, underscore), like this:

```
<script src='lib/underscore.js'></script>
<script src='lib/require.js' data-main='main.js'></script>
```

...and you have something like this in your requireJS config:

```
paths: {
    'underscore': 'lib/underscore'
},
shim: {
    'underscore': {
        exports: '_'
    }
}
```

Then the first time you do `define(['underscore'], function (_) {});` or `var _ = require('underscore');`, RequireJS will re-load the underscore library rather than re-using the previously defined `window._`, because as far as requireJS knows, you never loaded underscore before.  Sure, it can check to see if `_` is already defined on the root scope, but it has no way of verifying that the `_` that's already there is the same as the one defined in your `paths` config. For example, both `prototype` and `jquery` assign themselves to `window.$` by default, and if requireJS assumes that 'window.$' is jQuery when it is in fact prototype, you're going to be in a bad situation.

All of that means that if you mix-and-match script loading styles like that, your page will wind up with something like this:

```
 <script src='lib/underscore.js'></script>
 <script src='lib/require.js' data-main='main.js'></script>
 <script src='lib/underscore.js'></script>
```

Where the second underscore instance is the one loaded by requireJS.

Basically, a library has to be loaded via requireJS for requireJS to have knowledge of it.  However, the *next* time you require underscore, requireJS will go "hey, I already loaded that, so just hand back whatever the `exports` value is and don't worry about loading another script."

This means you have two real options.  One is what I would consider an anti-pattern: simply don't use requireJS to express dependencies for global scripts.  That is, as long as a library attaches a global to the root context, you'll be able to access it, event if that dependency isn't explicitly required.  You can see why this is an anti-pattern - you've basically just eliminated most of the advantages to using an AMD loader (explicit dependency listing and portability).

The other, better option is using requireJS to load everything, to the degree that the only actual script tag you should create yourself is the one that initially loads requireJS.  You can use shims, but 95% of the time it's really not that difficult to add an AMD wrapper to the script instead. It might take a little more work to convert all of your non-AMD libraries to be AMD compatible, but once you've done one or two it gets a lot easier - I can take any generic jQuery plugin and convert it to an AMD module in less than a minute.  It's usually just a matter of adding

```
define(['jquery'], function (jQuery) {
```

at the top, and

```
    return jQuery;
});
```

at the bottom.  The reason I have 'jquery' mapping to `jQuery` rather than `$` is that I've noticed most plugins these days are wrapped in a closure like this:

```
(function ($) {
    // plugin code here
})(jQuery);
```

And it's a good idea to pay attention to the intended scope.  You can certainly map 'jquery' to `$` directly though, assuming the plugin isn't expecting to find `jQuery` instead of `$`.  That's just the basic AMD wrapper - more complex ones generally try to detect what kind of loader is being used (commonJS vs AMD vs regular ol' globals) and use a different loading method depending on the result.  You can find examples of this pretty easily with a few seconds on google.

Update: The workaround I used to support using `jQuery.noConflict(true)` with RequireJS worked, but it required a very small modification to the jQuery source, and I have since figured out a much better way to accomplish the same thing without modifying jQuery. Luckily enough, so has James Burke, the author of RequireJS, who has added it to the RequireJS documentation: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#noconflictmap

Comment: This might be one of the single most helpful explanations of RequireJS  shim usage. The 'exports:' property is often confused as an indication of where RequireJS *should* attach the script, while in fact it is the place where it *looks* for it, as an indication it's ready. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it was helpful! I've spent a long time wrestling with requireJS so I've been forced to learn its idiosyncrasies, and I figured sharing what I've learned might help someone else avoid the same headaches I've gone through.