# Converting a Plain JQuery project to Require JS project

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have developed a JQuery project with multiple pages with dozens of JS scripts, but things became unmanageable and I'm getting lost in the thousands of lines of code. So I'm cleaning up and refactoring the whole structure and I'd like to organize the project with REquire JS.

basically all the pages will depend on `jquery.js, bootstrap.js, app.js`

and each page depends on other specifics scripts (moment.js etc...)

let's say I have this structure :

```
/
    header.html (all the CSS files etc..)
    footer.html (the global app.js file and other scripts : jquery / bootstrap etc...)
    page1.html (depends on app.js 
    page2.html
    page3.html
    page4.html
    page5.html 

    js /
        app.js
        require.js

        libs /
            jquery.js
            bootstrap.js
            moment.js
            knob.js
            fileuploader.js

        pages /
            page1.js (depends on JQuery and bootstrap and moment.js)
            page2.js (depends on JQuery and bootstrap and knob.js)
            page3.js (depends on JQuery and bootstrap and fileuploader.js)
            etc...
```

with header.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="//static.app.com/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//static.app.com/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//static.app.com/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//static.app.com/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//static.app.com/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    ....
```

and footer.html :

```
    ....
    <!--<script src="//static.app.com/js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="//static.app.com/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script data-main="//static.app.com/js/app.js" src="//static.app.com/js/require.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="//static.app.com/js/require.js"></script>
    <script src="//static.app.com/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="//static.app.com/js/logic.js"></script>-->
</body>
```

and every page.html :

```
{{> header}}
     <div></div>
     ....
{{> footer}}
```

So what I want to achieve is that I load dynamically only what needed per page so I don't have to include everything on my footer.html.

I've started reading about require and it seems that it fits this situation but I got lost in all the doc...

This is what I've done so far :

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": "libs/jquery.min",
        "bootstrap": "libs/bootstrap.min"
    },
    shim: {
        "jquery": {
            exports: "$"
         }, 
         "bootstrap": {
             deps: ["jquery"]
         }
    }
});
/*require(["jquery", "bootstrap"], function ($) {


});*/

function hello () {
    alert("hello");
}
```

But I can see that all the scripts I put on `paths` are being included.

Could you please, provide an easy and simple sample of what I want to achieve with require.js ? Thanks.

Comment: please post your HTML code as well

Comment: @Rahul : please see edits.

Comment: you dont need to give .js extention to data-main attribute.
also please check if this can help you http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/

also check more explanation of requirejs here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031485/require-js-is-hurting-my-brain-some-fundamental-questions-about-the-way-it-load